# Video recorded on android device doesn't play on web browser

Tags: php, android, video, browser, mp4

I have recorded video through my app (android application) and those videos doesn't plays on any of the web browser.
Required encoding for web browser is :
Video encoding(H264)
Audio encoding(AAC)

the video being recorded through device camera is :
Video encoding (MPEG_4_SP)
Audio encoding (AMR_NB)

Comment: Do you at least get audio?

Comment: Yes, but display is missing (black screen)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Android WebView,where it fails to play local videos in the Webview.
But if you try playing a video from a url, it would work fine.
I have spent a lot of time on this particular issue but failed to get it work and then I went Native.

Comment: We are recording videos on android device through a app and those videos doesn't plays on HTML5 based website on any web like mozilla, chrome, safari etc